# Routes.php in plugin directory not working for subdomain

Tags: octobercms

I am building a plugin for an OctoberCMS site and having a problem during Routes.php.

Within my plugin directory I created Routes.php file, and in it I have few lines like below (this is just for testing). When I test this line on my local machine with the domain mysite.dev, for example, it works fine. But when I try this on a remote server with subdomain such as dev.mysite.com it just returns 404 page.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'account/'], function() {
    Route::get('hell', [
        return 'Hello World';
    ]);
});
```

I have checked app.php and the line 32 has been changed to below.

```
'url' => 'http://dev.mysite.com/',
```

Also I tried to surround the above code with route grouping like below but this did not work either.

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'dev.mysite.com'], function () {
    Route::get('account/hello', function () {
        return 'Hello World';
    });
});
```

Could anyone know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

What's your file name?

> Routes.php

or

> routes.php

?
if it's Routes.php and your server is running on a linux distribution so changing file name to routes.php with lowercase R maybe solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in laravel, but on my plugin routes.php I use the following to access various methods on my desired  controller:

```
Route::get('your_controller/your_method/{id}', 'your_controller@your_method');
```

this works well on  my dev box and my deployment targets.